# Excluding sub modules in maven profile

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven multi module project which looks like below.

```
Parent
    |_ pom.xml
    |_ module1
    |   |_ pom.xml
    |_ module2
        |_ pom.xml
```

And I have a maven profile that I want to execute at Parent level only, module1 and module2 should not execute this profile. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your parent/pom.xml like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>aggregator</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile1</id>
      <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>profile2</id>
      <modules>
        <module>module2</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And run maven with this command line to install the modules inside of profile1 and profile2 respectively

```
mvn install -P profile1
```

This work for me running maven 3.1.1

To improve your profile definition you should take look at [Maven - Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I currently have , I don't want to run the profile for either module1 or module2 , I want it to run only for parent module...

Comment: So just leave your pom.xml without any module, and to reference your pom inside your children modules use without file reference, and you pom parent must be installed before you rum your children modules

Comment: I am not able to wrap my head around your suggestion above, however I solved my issue by creating additional child module, this child module does only one thing i.e. executes my special script.